# Select substring from table related to 2 other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here are the tables and their relationships:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqMRl.png)

I would like to get a number from the string InspectionDetails.Comments associated with the most recent entry by Repairs.DateOut and insert that into Scopes.CurrentUses for each record in Scopes. I only want to get those characters when InspectionDetails.Item = 1. The string will be formatted "Total uses=0000" where the number is variable length (eg, 1, 20, 1295, etc).

```
SELECT
  s1.ScopeName,
  r1.DateOut,
  i1.Comment
FROM Scopes s1
  INNER JOIN Repairs r1 ON s1.ID = r1.AssetID
  INNER JOIN InspectionDetails r1 ON r1.ID = i1.RepairID
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(r1.DateOut) AS DateOut
    FROM Scopes s
      INNER JOIN
      Repairs r ON s.ID = r.AssetID
      INNER JOIN
      InspectionDetails i ON r.ID = i.RepairID
    GROUP BY s.ID) i2 ON i1.ID = i2.ID
```

I think I'm a quarter way there, but I'm stuck getting Syntax errors and a still haven't figured out how to find and put that data into the field I would like. It would like this to happen when the form that the Repairs data is entered on is saved or navigated away from.

[Repairs Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWXNv.png)

I've attached a picture of the blank form as well. The save button saves the main form while the subforms are saved on TAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specify the Id in the subquery for `i2`. This surely is a problem, not the single one though :) Clearly you don't need the `Repairs` table since you referencing it in the subquery. I see just the aggregated field in the `SELECT` list.

For both brevity and readability of your queries, you can write and save your subqueries separately. Then in your main query just add them as tables and perform the necessary joins etc.

E.g. given your situation create a query named `_LatestRepair` like so:

```
SELECT s.ID AS ScopeId, r.ID AS RepairID, MAX(r1.DateOut) AS DateOut
FROM Scopes s
  INNER JOIN Repairs r ON s.ID = r.AssetID
GROUP BY s.ID, r.ID
```

Then add this `_LatestRepair` query as table to your main query like this:

```
SELECT s1.ScopeName, r1.DateOut, i1.Comments
FROM (_LatestRepair r1 INNER JOIN Scopes s1 ON s1.ID = r1.ScopeId)        
    INNER JOIN InspectionDetails i1 ON r1.RepairId = i1.RepairID
```

**UPDATE**

And here's how you parse the number out of the comment field:

```
SELECT s1.ScopeName, r1.DateOut, i1.Comments,
    InStr([I1].[Comments],"=") AS Expr1, 
    IIf([Expr1]>0,Val(Right([i1].[Comments],Len([i1].[comments])-[expr1]))) AS Expr2
FROM (_LatestRepair r1 INNER JOIN Scopes s1 ON s1.ID = r1.ScopeId)        
    INNER JOIN InspectionDetails i1 ON r1.RepairId = i1.RepairID
```

Comment: Makes sense, get the most recent repair first, then look up the comment based on that. Only problem is I'm getting "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 's1.ID = r1.ScopeID INNER JOIN InspectionDetails i1 ON r1.RepairID = i1.RepairID'"

Comment: Yes, though I get a list with all of the repairs done for each scope instead of just the most recent. I'm embarrassingly rusty at SQL and it seems to be every so slightly harder to get to work with Access...

Comment: I admit that I didn't test those queries, but they should work as this is simple expressions. Maybe you can send me example database and I'll take a look...

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/55m9a0jpsc0l4g4/Example%20DB.accdb?dl=0) Here you go, it should have enough data to show what I'm trying. The forms I use are Scopes List and Repairs List. I couldn't save the second query into the database because of the error I encountered. The first query is named _LastestRepair as above. I checked and this copy also throws the syntax error. I feel pretty confident it is just a simple problem that I can't see through my SQL cobwebs.

Comment: Oh man. It's the parenthesis. I've updated the code example. It appears that in MS Access, each result set expression within the `FROM` clause must be enclosed in parenthesis. But don't you use the query designer? I find this immediately by designing the query in the designer and look at the generated SQL.

Comment: I had actually resorted to using SQL because I couldn't finagle the designer to do what I was trying to do! Thank you very much for your help!